# Source code of a CSS3 animated style

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, hover

Browsing the [Handimania](http://www.handimania.com/) website I realised the title was pulsing one time when the mouse would hover it. Now I know this could probably be a style-animation done with CSS or CSS3 (am I correct?) but I am not too sure about how I can *see* the source code.

So far, when an appealing static webpage was popping in front of me I could just scan it's *html* in order to get its secrets and insights. Now I find myself unable to approach this dynamic content in the same way. What I can tell so far is that there should be, somwhere, a class called `hover` which in turn fades from 0% to 100% and back to 0% a cyano PNG title with a transparent background over a static grey image.

This is the furthest I can go

```
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://www.handimania.com/wp-content/themes/handimania/images/logo.png" alt="Handimania" class="hover"/>
<h1>
<img class="dark" src="http://www.handimania.com/wp-content/themes/handimania/images/logo-dark.png" alt="Handimania"/>
</h1>
<p id="tagline">Guides for Handmade, DIY &amp; Crafts Maniacs</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's likely this piece of code:

```
$('#logo .hover').hover(
    function(e) {
        console.log('enter');
        $('#logo .hover').animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
        $('#logo .dark').animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");
    },
    function(e) {
        console.log('leave')
        $('#logo .dark').animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
        $('#logo .hover').animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");
    }
);
```

which is in the included file `jquery.custom.js?ver=1.0` and shows that it's a jQuery animation, not a CSS3 animation.